# resharper test runner - how to execute by category?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, resharper

Resharper version 7.1

Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Two part question:

Q1: When I select "run unit tests" in the solution explorer resharper automatically opens a test fixture runner and executes ALL test fixtures. However, I have categorized tests in to two categories: 1) "long running" and 2) "short running". Is there a way that after performing these steps that I can have the test runner execute "short running", only?

Q2: With the test fixture runner open, I select Group By "Categories". I see the two categories I mention above. I right click on "short running" and select "run tests". Expected is that only the "short running" tests will execute; however, BOTH the "long running" and "short running" execute. Is there a way to execute by category, and have only that category execute?

UPDATE: here is what is showing on my screen

First: R#->Options->Unit Testing (general tab)

[image]

Second: an example test from a random testfixture, showing usage.

[image]

Third:  this is what I see when I execute "run unit test" from Solution Explorer, and also what I see when I right click on "short running"->"run tests" (in either case, "long running" also executes)

[image]

Comment: notice that "long running" is Running (displayed in third picture). According to what I've read and what other people have tried, this should not be Running. I can't seem to determine what is causing this issue. I've tried restarting Visual Studio several times. I also confirmed that the Resharper options are indeed saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the long running tests actually running? I know it seems like a silly question, but if both long and short running tests share a test fixture, it might look like they're running, as in the screenshot you posted, but it's only the shared fixture that's run, not the actual tests. In other words, test fixtures get a node in the tree of results, and if it's shared by the tests, it can appear multiple times in the tree. At the point that the fixture runs, the test runner doesn't know what test is about to run, so marks all fixture nodes in the tree as running, although it's only the shared fixture itself that's running. It will then run the actual test, and only the tests that run are marked as running.

Comment: Wow. Not a silly question. You nailed it: while running, it appears as if  "long running" is actually running. But when "short running" completes,  "long running" automatically switches to IGNORED state.

Comment: I wrote the folks at jetbrains an email asking them to revisit this behavior. Thanks citizenmatt.

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to apply category attributes to the test methods (in xUnit.Net you can use `Traits` with the name *Category*. (If you have separated your tests along Test classes/fixtures, you can apply these attributes to the classes.)

Then, based on these categories, you can make R# to only execute test methods that have one of the specified categories. You do this in the *RESHARPER|Options* dialog. Under *Unit Testing*, on the *General* tab, there's an input field for this.

Comment: There is an option in Resharper->Options->UnitTesting->"don't include categories.." (separated by comma). I added "long running" to the list (no quotes, or comma - there is only one item I want to exclude). Result: all tests still ran relative to Q1 and Q2 above. I expected it to exclude "long running". Any ideas?

Comment: Did you apply the attributes to each test method and did you also make sure that you don't have a typo somewhere?

Comment: i added three pictures showing what I tried, do you see any typos/technical issues?

Comment: Hmm. Nothing obvious. I'd expect that to work, too. What you could try is to avoid the space in your category, i.e. replace it with 'LongRunning' or sth. similar...

Comment: This should be the answer to your question @sapbucket